# Is it possible to install GccEmacs for Emacs 27.2

Tags: gccemacs

For installing `GccEmacs`, I have followed:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs

> ```
> git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
> cd emacs
> ./autogen.sh
> ./configure --with-native-compilation
> make -j$(nproc)
> ```

which installs: `GNU Emacs 28.0.50`. As I understand its an experimental / developmental version of Emacs not yet released to the general public.

Instead how can I build `GccEmacs` for Emacs'sreleased version, I believe for Emacs 27.2?

I have tried `it checkout tags/emacs-27.2` , but it gives following error:
`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-native-compilation`

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible to run GCCEmacs changes with Emacs 27.2. All the related modifications are in the current main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want -- GccEmacs is being developed for Emacs 28.

> For installing GccEmacs, I have followed: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs which installs: GNU Emacs 28.0.50. As I understand its an experimental / developmental version of Emacs not yet released to the general public.

The native compilation feature is in an equally experimental / developmental state, so even if you could make it work with Emacs 27, you would be acting contrary to your stated motivation for avoiding Emacs 28.

Lots of people use Emacs 28 with native compilation on a daily basis, so "developmental" doesn't mean "crashing constantly"; but you should still assume you'll encounter some issues when using unstable builds.

Comment: I encounter some issues :-( Once in a while emacs's display freezes, `C-g` does not responds back (I have no idea what causes this but happend when I do page down/up), Ondebug I see: `display wait = FOREVER`. Whom could I reach for this issue?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`